# Joomla adding form fields dynamically to config.xml

Tags: xml, forms, joomla

**Edited to add more info**

I am developing a component in which I need to configure it adding some info to every installed language; some sort of mapping language-name/custom-code.

I have created in *config.xml* a custom form field called *languagegrid* that is dynamically populated with rows containing installed language - code selection list

In my *config.xml* I have

```
<fieldset name="language_mapping"
            label="LANGUAGE_MAPPING"
            description=""
            addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_mycomponent/models/fields">
            <field name="languagegrid"
                type="LanguageGrid"
            >
            </field>
</fieldset>
```

and the **getInput** function of my *languagegrid* form field populates it

```
public function getInput() {    
    ...
    foreach($installed languages as $lang) {
        ...
        $html .= "<td>".$lang->name."</td>";
        $html .= '<td><select id="'.$this->id.'" name="'.$this->name.'">';
        $html .=  '<option value...>...</option>';
        ...
        $html .=  '<option value...>...</option>';
        $html .= '</select></td>';
    }
    ...

    return $html;
}
```

The point is that the select name, *this->name*, is the name of the field so every select overwrites the same value. 
I have tried using different names for each select but then no values are saved. It seems only the field name is possible.

So my second approach is to insert dynamically various field, each one with one select, but I haven't found how to make it (if possible). Is this option feasible?

Comment: This is hard to understand, but you probably want to save it as json and to use unique names.  But is this really the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: Yes, jason and unique names. Is this the most efficient way? I don't know if it is; I have read some tutorials and I just wanted to do the same as explained in them. I don't have too much experience in Joomla ;)

Comment: If you wrap your `field` tags inside a `fields` tag with a name that matches  the field to be stored in it will automatically create json for you.  In the case of config you already have this is the params field and if you out these fields inside the params it should work.  But what are you going to do if a new language is installed after you make these values?

Comment: "what are you going to do if a new language is installed?" That is the point, I would need add dynamically new field tags but I don't know if it is possible

Comment: Adding something on installing a new language is much easier than trying to add it using a form. To me it makes much more sense for you to do it programmatically than via xml.